# Why is this ESP32 IDF example file throwing so many errors?

Tags: python, apple-m1, esp32

I'm attempting to setup a UART communication between an ESP32 and STM32 using the Espressif IDF through VScode on a  macbook pro using the M1 processor. Below I have provided an image of one of the problems I've been encountering and cant seem to find anything on the internet with a similar situation to my own. I previously had this example working but that no longer seems to be the case and I havent made any changes to the code since it's last usage.

Another error I seem to be recieving is in relation to my processor I believe but I have no idea how to go about fixing it? I can't seem to build any projects in VS code or even run python scripts that previously worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

[image]

I've attempted to uninstall VS code from my mac and looked through a ridiculous amount of forums and webpages but nothing specific enough to my problem that has helped.

after uninstalling my anaconda3 files and reinstalling I'm now receiving this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw4mV.jpg)

Comment: because your build system is broken :)

Comment: oh, do you know how I could go about fixing it? Should I just uninstall and start all over?

Comment: Reinstall it - easiest